# Iterator losing reference in a list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

My problem was in the main function. Whenever i casted remove(), the iterator pointed to thrash data. After investigating, I found out the problem was in the main. I was trying to use multiple remove with the same iterator in a loop, wich isn't a correct use , even though it compiles. I compared the list I created with de std::list and it turns out std::list has the same output when you try to use remove with the same iterator in a loop.

Here is my list(please ignore the comments, they are in portuguese):

```
template <typename T>
class Lista
{
 private:
  struct Node
  {
   Node()
   {
    prox = NULL;
    ant = NULL;
   }
   Node (T _data)
   {
    data = _data;
    prox = ant = NULL;
   }
   Node (T _data, Node * _prox, Node * _ant)
   {
    data = _data;
    prox = _prox;
    ant = _ant;
   }
   T data;  
   Node* prox; //Points to previous element
   Node* ant;  //Points to next elemente
  };
  Node* first; 
  Node* last;  
  unsigned length=0; //size
 public:

  //Classe iterador
  class iterator
  {
   public:
   friend class Lista<T>;

   Node * pNode;

   iterator(Node * _pNode)
   {
     pNode = _pNode;
   }

   iterator()
   {
    pNode = NULL;
   }

     void operator++()
     {
      if(pNode)
       pNode = pNode->prox;
     }
     void operator--()
     {
      if(pNode)
       pNode = pNode->ant;
     }
     void operator--(int)
     {
      if(pNode)
       pNode = pNode->ant;
     }
     void operator++(int)
     {
      if(pNode)
       pNode = pNode->prox;
     }
     bool operator==(iterator rval)
     {
      return (pNode == rval.pNode);
     }
     bool operator!=(iterator rval)
     {
      return !(pNode == rval.pNode);
     }
     T operator*()
     {
      if(pNode)
       return pNode->data;
      return T();
     }
     iterator operator+(unsigned _i)
     {
      iterator iter = *this;
      for (unsigned i = 0; i < _i; ++i)
      {
       if (iter.pNode)
        ++iter;
       else
         break;
      }
      return iter;
      }
  };

  //Classe iterador reverso
  class reverse_iterator
  {
    friend class Lista<T>;

    Node * pNode;

    reverse_iterator(Node * _pNode)
    {
     pNode = _pNode;
    }

    reverse_iterator()
    {
     pNode = NULL;
    }
     public:
      void operator++()
      {
       if(pNode)
        pNode = pNode->ant;
      }
      void operator--()
      {
       if(pNode)
        pNode = pNode->prox;
      }
      void operator--(int)
      {
       if(pNode)
        pNode = pNode->prox;
      }
      void operator++(int)
      {
       if(pNode)
        pNode = pNode->ant;
      }
      bool operator!=(reverse_iterator rval)
      {
       return !(pNode == rval.pNode);
      }
      bool operator==(reverse_iterator rval)
      {
       return (pNode == rval.pNode);
      }
      T operator*()
      {
       if(pNode)
        return pNode->data;
       return T();
      }
      reverse_iterator operator+(int _i)
      {
       reverse_iterator iter = *this;
       for (int i = 0; i < _i; ++i)
       {
        if (iter.pNode)
         ++iter;
        else
          break;
       }
       return iter;
       }
   };

  //Construtor Padrão
  Lista()
  {
   first = last = NULL;
  }

  //Contrutor "fill"(veja std::list para detalhes)
  Lista(unsigned n, const T& val)
  {
   first = last = NULL;
   for(unsigned i=0; i< n;i++)
    push_front(val);
  }

  //construtor "range"(veja std::list para detalhes)
  Lista(iterator inicio, iterator fim)
  {
   first = last = NULL;
   insert(begin(),inicio,fim);
  }

  //construtor por cópia
  Lista(const Lista& l)
  {
   first = last = NULL;
   Node* temp = l.first;
   while(temp != NULL)
   {
    push_back(temp->data);
    temp = temp->prox;
   }
  }

  //Destrutor
  ~Lista()
  {
   if (!empty())
   {
    Node * iter = first;
    Node * tmp = iter;
    while (iter != NULL)
    {
     tmp = iter;
     iter = iter->prox;
     delete tmp;
     length--;
    }
   }
  }

  //Retorna um iterador que aponta para o primeiro elemento da lista
  iterator begin()
  {
   return iterator(first);
  }

  //Retorna um iterador que aponta para o proximo elemento depois do ultimo("past-the-end")
  iterator end()
  {
   return iterator(NULL); // MUDANÇA AKI: DE LAST->PROX PRA NULL
  }

  //Retorna um iterador reverso que aponta para o ultimo elemento da lista
  reverse_iterator rbegin()
  {
   return reverse_iterator(last);
  }

  //Retorna um iterador reverso que aponta para o elemento teórico que antecede o primeior elemnto da lista
  reverse_iterator rend()
  {
   return reverse_iterator(NULL); // MUDANÇA AKI: DE FIRST->ANT PRA NULL
  }

  //Verifica se a lista está vazia, retornado "true" caso positivo
  bool empty()const
  {
   return (first == last && first == NULL);
  }

  //Retorna o numero de elementos da lista
  unsigned size()const
  {
   return length;
  }

  //Retorna uma referência direta para o primeiro elemento da lista(first)
  T front()
  {
   if(first)
   {
    return first->data;
   }
  }

  //Retorna uma referência direta para o ultimo elemento da lista(last)
  T back()
  {
   if(last)
   {
    return last->data;
   }
  }

  //Insere um novo elemento(nó) no inicio da lista
  void push_front(const T& val)
  {
   if(!empty())
   {
    Node* temp = new Node(val);
    temp->prox = first;
    first->ant = temp;
    first = temp;
    length++;
   }
   else
   {
    Node* temp = new Node(val);
    first = last = temp;
    length++;
   }
  }

  //Remove e destroi o primeiro elemento(nó) da lista
  void pop_front()
  {
    if(size() == 1)
    {
     Node* temp = first;
     first = last = NULL;
     delete temp;
     length--;
    }
    else if (size()>1)
    {
     Node* temp = first;
     first = first->prox;
     first->ant = NULL;
     delete temp;
     length--;
    }
  }

  //Insere um novo elemento(nó) no fim da lista
  void push_back(const T& val)
  {
   if(!empty())
   {
    Node* temp = new Node(val);
    last->prox = temp;
    temp->ant = last;
    last = temp;
    length++;
   }
   else
   {
    Node* temp = new Node(val);
    first = last = temp;
    length++;
   }
  }

  //Remove e destroi o ultimo elemento(nó) da lista
  void pop_back()
  {
   if(size() ==1)
   {
    Node* temp = last;
    first = last = NULL;
    delete temp;
    length--;
   }
   else if(size()>1)
   {
    Node* temp = last;
    last = last->ant;
    last->prox = NULL;
    delete temp;
    length--;
   }
  }

  //Insert "single element"(veja std::list para detalhes)
  iterator insert(iterator position,const T&val)
  {
   if(!empty())
   {
    if(position != begin() && position != end())
    {
     Node* temp = new Node(val);
     for(iterator it = begin();it!=end();it++)
     {
      if(it.pNode->prox == position.pNode)
      {
       it.pNode->prox = temp;
       temp->ant = it.pNode;
       temp->prox = position.pNode;
       position.pNode->ant = temp;
       length++;
       return iterator(temp);
      }
     }
    }
    else
    {
     if(position == begin())
     {
      push_front(val);
      return iterator(first);
     }
     else if (position == end())
     {
      push_back(val);
      return iterator(last);
     }
    }
   }
   push_front(val);
   return iterator(first);
  }

  //Insert "fill"(veja std::list para detalhes)
  void insert (iterator position, unsigned n, const T& val)
  {
   iterator it = position;
   while(n)
   {
    it = insert(it,val);
    n--;
   }

  }

  //Insert "range"(veja std::list para detalhes)
  void insert (iterator position, iterator primeiro, iterator ultimo)
  {
   if(position != NULL)
   {
    if(ultimo != end() && primeiro != end())
    {
     iterator it = position;
     while( primeiro != ultimo)
     {
      it = insert(it,*ultimo);
      ultimo--;
     }
     it = insert(it,*primeiro);
    }
    else if( ultimo == end() && primeiro != end())
    {
     ultimo = primeiro;
     iterator it = position;
     do
     {
      ultimo++;
     }while(ultimo.pNode->prox);

     while( primeiro != ultimo)
     {
      it = insert(it,*ultimo);
      ultimo--;
     }
     it = insert(it,*primeiro);
    }
   }
   else
   {
    first = last = NULL;
    if(primeiro.pNode != NULL && ultimo.pNode != NULL)
    {
     while(primeiro != ultimo)
     {
      push_front(*ultimo);
      ultimo--;
     }
     push_front(*primeiro);
    }
    else
    {
     if(ultimo.pNode == NULL && primeiro.pNode != NULL)
     {
      ultimo = primeiro;
      do
      {
       ultimo++;
      }while(ultimo.pNode->prox);

      while( primeiro != ultimo)
      {
       push_front(*ultimo);
       ultimo--;
      }
      push_front(*primeiro);
     }
    }
   }
  }

  //Remove um único elemento(nó) de determinada posição da lista,retornando um iterador que aponta para o elemento seguinte
  //aquele removido/destruido por ultimo.
  iterator erase (iterator position)
  {
   if(!empty())
   {
    if(position != end())
    {
     if(size() == 1)
     {
      pop_front();
      return end();
     }
     else
     {
      iterator it = begin();
      while(it != end())
      {
       if(it == position)
       {
        if(position != begin() && position.pNode != last) //MUDANÇA: position != end() para position.pNode != last
        {
         Node* temp = position.pNode->ant;
         position++;
         temp->prox = position.pNode;
         position.pNode->ant = temp;
         delete it.pNode;
         length--;
         return position;
        }
        else
        {
         if(position == begin())
         {
          //Node* temp = first; //MUDANÇA: Tirou o novo nó
          position = it.pNode->prox; //MUDANÇA: position = temp->prox; para position = it.pNode->prox;
          first = position.pNode;
          first->ant = NULL; //ADICIONADO
          delete it.pNode; //MUDANÇA: delete tempo para delete it.pNOde
          length--;
          return position;
         }
         else if(position.pNode == last) //MUDANÇA: position != end() para position.pNode != last
         {
          //Node* temp = last; //MUDANÇA: Tirou o novo nó
          position = end(); //MUDANÇA: position =  temp->prox para position = end()
          last = it.pNode->ant; //MUDANÇA: last = position.pNode para last = it.pNode->ant
          last->prox = NULL; //ADICIONADO
          delete it.pNode; //MUDANÇA: delete tempo para delete it.pNOde
          length--;
          return position;
         }
        }
       }
       it++;
      }
     }
    }
    else
     return end();
   }
   else
     return end();
  }

  //Remove todos elementos(nós) de um intervalo da lista(inclusive o apontado por "primeiro" e exclusive o apontado por "ultimo"),
  //retornando um iterador que aponta para o elemento seguinte aquele removido/destruido por ultimo.
  iterator erase (iterator primeiro, iterator ultimo)
  {
   if(ultimo.pNode)
   {
    for(iterator it = primeiro; it != ultimo;)
     it = erase(it);
    return ultimo;
   }
   else
   {
    iterator itaux = begin()+(size()-1);
    for(iterator it = primeiro;it!=itaux;)
     it = erase(it);
    return ultimo;
   }
  }

  //Remove da lista todos os elementos(nós) cujo conteúdo se compara igualmente com "val"


     iteratorvoid remove (const T& val)
  {
    for(iterator it = begin();it != end();)
    {
     if(*it == val)
       it = erase(it);
     else
      it++;
    }
  }

  //Inverte a ordem dos elementos(nós) da lista
  void reverse()
  {
   if(empty() || size() == 1)
    return;
   else
   {
    Node* temp1 = first;
    Node* temp2 = temp1->prox;
    temp1->prox = NULL;
    temp1->ant = temp2;
    while(temp2 != NULL)
    {
     temp2->ant = temp2->prox;
     temp2->prox = temp1;
     temp1 = temp2;
     temp2 = temp2->ant;
    }
    last = first;
    first = temp1;
   }
  }
};
```

Here is the main(please ignore the comments, they are in portuguese):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cassert>
#include <list>

#include "Lista.h" // ------ ALTERAR AQUI

#define N 500

typedef Lista<int> lista_ref_type;
//typedef std::list< int > lista_ref_type;
typedef std::list< int > lista_type;

void compare( lista_type &lista, lista_ref_type &lista_ref ) {

    lista_type::iterator it = lista.begin();
    lista_ref_type::iterator it_ref = lista_ref.begin();
    while( it_ref != lista_ref.end() ) {
        assert( it != lista.end() );
        assert( *it == *it_ref);
        it++;
        it_ref++;
    }
    assert( it == lista.end() );
    return;
}

int main() {

    lista_ref_type lista_ref;
    lista_type lista;

    srand( time(NULL) );

    assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
    assert( lista_ref.empty() == lista.empty() );

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int valor = rand();
        if( valor/RAND_MAX > 0.5 ) {
            lista_ref.push_back(valor);
            lista.push_back(valor);
        } else {
            lista_ref.push_front(valor);
            lista.push_front(valor);
        }
        assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        assert( lista_ref.empty() == lista.empty() );
    }

    compare( lista, lista_ref);
    std::cout << "Etapa 1: OK!" << std::endl;

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        assert( lista_ref.empty() == lista.empty() );
        assert( lista_ref.front() == lista.front() );
        assert( lista_ref.back() == lista.back() );

        int valor1 = rand()%lista.size();

        lista_type::iterator it = lista.begin();
        lista_ref_type::iterator it_ref = lista_ref.begin();
        while(valor1) {
            assert( it_ref != lista_ref.end() );
            assert( it != lista.end() );
            assert( *it == *it_ref);
            it++;
            it_ref++;
            valor1--;
        }
        assert( *it == *it_ref);
        //lista.remove( *it );                     //THE PROBLEM IS HERE. I CANT CALL REMOVE(*IT) IN THIS LOOP
        //lista_ref.remove( *it_ref );              //THE PROBLEM IS HERE. I CANT CALL REMOVE(*IT) IN THIS LOOP
    }

    //assert( lista.empty() );
    //assert( lista_ref.empty() );
    std::cout << "Etapa 2: OK!" << std::endl;

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int valor = rand();
        if( valor/RAND_MAX > 0.5 ) {
            lista_ref.push_back(valor);
            lista.push_back(valor);
        } else {
            lista_ref.push_front(valor);
            lista.push_front(valor);
        }
    assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        //assert( lista_ref.empty() == lista.empty() );
    }

    compare( lista, lista_ref);
    std::cout << "Etapa 3: OK!" << std::endl;

    lista.reverse();
    lista_ref.reverse();

    compare( lista, lista_ref);
    std::cout << "Etapa 4: OK!" << std::endl;

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        //assert( lista_ref.empty() == lista.empty() );
        assert( lista_ref.front() == lista.front() );
        assert( lista_ref.back() == lista.back() );
        int valor = rand();
        if( valor/RAND_MAX > 0.5 ) {
            lista_ref.pop_back();
            lista.pop_back();
        } else {
            lista_ref.pop_front();
            lista.pop_front();
        }
    }

    //assert( lista.empty() );
    //assert( lista_ref.empty() );
    std::cout << "Etapa 5: OK!" << std::endl;

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        int valor1 = rand()%(lista.size()+1);
        int valor2 = rand();
        if(valor1 == lista.size())
            valor1 = 0;

        lista_type::iterator it = lista.begin();
        lista_ref_type::iterator it_ref = lista_ref.begin();
        while( it_ref != lista_ref.end() && valor1) {
            assert( it != lista.end() );
            assert( *it == *it_ref);
            it++;
            it_ref++;
            valor1--;
        }
        lista.insert( it, valor2);
        lista_ref.insert( it_ref, valor2);
    }

    compare( lista, lista_ref);
    std::cout << "Etapa 6: OK!" << std::endl;

    for( int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        assert( lista_ref.size() == lista.size() );
        int valor1 = rand()%lista.size();
        int valor2 = rand();

        lista_type::iterator it = lista.begin();
        lista_ref_type::iterator it_ref = lista_ref.begin();
        while(valor1) {
            assert( it_ref != lista_ref.end() );
            assert( it != lista.end() );
            assert( *it == *it_ref);
            it++;
            it_ref++;
            valor1--;
        }
        lista.erase( it);
        lista_ref.erase( it_ref );
    }

    //assert( lista.empty() );
    //assert( lista_ref.empty() );
    std::cout << "Etapa 7: OK!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "UFA!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "my remove function in a class list"? Did you implement your own list?

Comment: This code is **incomplete**, not showing the definitions of free functions (or perhaps member of user-defined class?) `begin()`, `end()` and `erase()`.

Comment: I implemented my own list(yeah, my teacher asked this :/). I added my full implementation code :)

Comment: Why have edited your question so that it makes the whole thing useless?

Comment: You want me to repost? i edited so nobody loses time trying to solve something that didnt need to be be solved. But if you want, i can repost it

Comment: Is there a way i can tag this question as solved so nobody losses their time? That's why i edited the qeustion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the specific case of removing the first item only, with guaranteed at least one item remaining, all you have to do is move the iterator ahead before the removal.

However, in general you don't even know whether there will be any items left that the iterator can refer to.

So for the general case you have to decide on what you want, and include consideration of the case where nothing's left.

Comment: I added my erase function. I believe it treats this case,doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks guys. Turns out the error was in the main, not in the functions! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to advance the iterator past the element you're removing, before you remove it.

Something like (not tested)

```
    for(iterator it = begin();it != end();)
    {
     iterator current = it++;

     if(*current == val)
       erase(current);
    }
```

or, of course, use the library algorithm http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html

Comment: The problem is not in the loop. It's in the code in `main`. For which your solution (shown in the body of the loop) works for the specific case of removing exactly one item.

Comment: `it = erase(it);` does this fine, assuming `erase` is following the usual `std::list::erase` semantics, to wit returning the iterator immediateyl following the erased element.

Comment: Yeah. it = erase(it) advances the iterator past the element im removing